# Merge dataframes without matching column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, cross-join

I have the following two dataframes:

```
df1:
column_01   value_01
aaa         1
bbb         2

df2:
column_02   value_02
ccc         3
ddd         4
```

I need to merge the dataframes such that the rows in `df1` are duplicated to contain a row for every row in `df2`. The output would be as follows:

```
column_01   value_01   column_02   value_02
aaa         1          ccc         3
aaa         1          ddd         4
bbb         2          ccc         3
bbb         2          ddd         4
```

I have tried variations of `merge` and `join`, but can't get it working because I am not matching column values, I am purposely trying to duplicate `df1` rows for each `df2` row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use create new columns with some scalar value and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by these columns:

```
df1['one'] = 1
df2['one'] = 1
print (pd.merge(df1, df2, on='one').drop('one', axis=1))
  column_01  value_01 column_02  value_02
0       aaa         1       ccc         3
1       aaa         1       ddd         4
2       bbb         2       ccc         3
3       bbb         2       ddd         4
```

Comment: Good idea. Thanks!